# Что такое $.support.cors?

Tags: jquery

Что такое $.support.cors? Что дает установка этого флага на true?

Answer (score 1):

Установка ничего не даёт. Все атрибуты $.support только для чтения. Конкретно этот указывает, поддерживаются ли кросс-доменные запросы. Кроме того, $.support устарела и не рекомендована к использованию.